# Xcode (Version 9.2 (9C40b)): C++ Semantic and linker issues when trying to include boost

Tags: c++, xcode, boost, linker-errors, semantics

I am currently working on a masters project and I am desperately trying to compile some C++ code on my mac (macOS High Sierra 10.13.3 using Xcode) so I can develop the program at home. The Program is a set of files used for performing integrals on a bunch of different data... it uses headers from the boost library and also alglib. This all works fine on Windows machines running visual studios.

The issue I have is that when I include boost (which was installed via homebrew to usr/local/) into the search paths in the project build settings I get all sorts of semantic and linker issues.

I have searched this for a while and tried to implement a few potential fixes. I have tried:

Compiling with different C++ dialects and and standard libraries (libc++ and libstdc++).

Uninstalling/reinstalling boost.

Removing suggested header files and libraries from 'usr/local' suggested by brew doctor.

and implementing all sorts of other random permutations of settings that I felt could be issued.

The number of errors and warnings may change using different build settings however semantic issues persist and I am running out of ideas for how to proceed. It is really important I get this working and any insight would be appreciated.

From my reading about and attempting to troubleshoot I get the idea that it is some kind of linking issue between the boost library and the standard c++ libraries, but I have little experience with semantic issues as in the past I have been lucky enough that things just worked! Perhaps my MacBook may just have too much going on and needs some housecleaning to stop confusing the compiler, but regardless if anyone can help me fix this issue I would be eternally grateful!

I understand I haven't provided much detail here but if any information would be useful I'm happy to send screenshots.

[link to errors image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ibEB.jpg)

Comment: Can you post the actual errors you are getting?

Comment: ok so i just tried to compile with... c++ Language dialect : GNU++11 and c++ standard library libstdc++  and i get 5 errors:

Comment: The list of the errors would be more helpful

Comment: No matching constructor for initialization of 'std::ifstream' (aka 'basic_ifstream<char>')

Comment: all the errors are essentially the same as that

Comment: I will edit my original post to give a link to a picture of the errors

Comment: pictures of errors are less good than just the error strings

Answer (score 1):

In C++03 `ifstream` did not have a constructor that accepts `std::string`.

Such a constructor was added in C++11. The same holds [for `std::stod`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/stod/): it exists since C++11.

So you have to compile with `-std=c++11` option.

Comment: and that is available in your target, or project build settings